# Manually specifying address of string in memory

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory-management

Is it nearly possible for one to assign a memory address to a **char*** and if so, then how?
Assuming we have an existing address .. just like that:

```
char *string_received = (char*)0x30123f00;
```

Resulting in an allocated string, obtained directly from memory.

Comment: Where do you get that memory address from? If you know that address represents a valid memory address then yes.

Comment: Your address should read `0x30123f00` btw ;)

Comment: Okay, it was figurative though.
And yes, in real life, this is a real existing address.

Comment: have a chance to have a segfault if you just input some random address. are you running under real mode or what, so that you want to do that?

Comment: Once again.. it isn't random address.

Comment: just curious how you get address directly. embedded system? trying to read bytes from registers?

Comment: I use the `printf()` format specifier `%p` to obtain the offset address of a string, then output it to a file stream, read it from another program meanwhile using `fscanf()`s format specifier `%p` to store it in `int`, then `memcpy(buff, (char*)address, 5)` in order to obtain 5 characters from that memory location.

Comment: No you can't with two programs (in general)! Each running program/process has its own memory space and address A in process P1 has nothing to do with address A in process P2, even if P1 and P2 runs the same program. This is called virtual memory, it is intended for memory protection and security. In some very particular case you can, but this is very specific (memory mapped ports or things like that); I am pretty sure that this is not what you thought about.

Comment: it will fail in modern OSes. this is the trick could be done in real mode(intel terminology), but in protected mode, as i said, you will have a chance to have a segfault.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. However, the string is not "allocated", it just exists. You have to be sure there is something valid at that memory location before using the pointer.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Do you mind giving an example of working mechanism? I tried using `memmove`, but it doesn't print anything.

Comment: I'll also add that if you're using this to access memory mapped IO ports, you should add `volatile` to your pointer so they compiler doesn't re-order or optimise your memory accesses.